# .htaccess RedirectMatch regex issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I’m trying a redirection with this code in my `.htaccess` file. What’s wrong with it?

It runs seamlessly without regex (first line) but no way to execute the redirection with regex on the second line.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /videos/100067.mp4 http://test.com/video/100067/dfts4555444.mp4

RedirectMatch 301 /videos/^([0-9]+)?$.mp4 http://test.com/video/$1/([a-z0-9]+).mp4
```

Comment: @Xufox Yes .. there should be!

Answer (score 0):

`^` and `$` match the start and end of a string, respectively.

Something like this should work better:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/videos/([0-9]+)\.mp4$ http://test.com/video/$1/$1.mp4
```

I have no idea where you are getting the last part of the resulting url from, the `dfts4555444.mp4` part. I used `$1` to make it work for now.